# koshering a keli less than 212 farenheit

Tags: kashrut-kosher

my wife made Hagala in a vessel and the water was not boiling yet. I measure the temperature after she did it and it was 80 degrees celsius (176 F). whats the din now. can i used or i have to kasher again ? thanks

Comment: http://oukosher.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Daf-16-5.pdf

Comment: there might be a difference if what you were trying to kasher was on the fire or not when it came in contact with whatever it was that requires you to kasher it.